# React-native. on iOS cyrillic symbols are appearing for a moment and than disappearing

Tags: ios, react-native

At the TextInput, cyrillic symbols are appearing for a moment and then disappearing, especially when entering the symbols quickly, so that the kind of blinking is observed. I am wondering if it is possible to fix

I tried to use debounce
`debounce(updateAnswer, 300);`
It does not help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.